# MySQL Query giving duplicates

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble getting my query to return unique results.

`users_systems` db setup:
  int   id
  int   user_id
  int   system_id
  int   mic`

example `users_systems` data:
  id    user_id system_id   mic
  1 1   1       1
  2 1   3       0

`users_gamernames` db setup

int id
  int user_id
  int system_id
  varchar user_name

example `users_gamernames` data
  id    user_id system_id   user_name
  1 1   1       jayr0xx
  2 1   3       jayrox

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users_systems.system_id, users_systems.mic users_gamers.user_name
FROM users_systems  
LEFT JOIN users_gamernames ON users_gamernames.user_id = users_systems.user_id  
WHERE users_systems.user_id =4  
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

which returns:

  `system_id mic user_name

  1     0   jayrox

  1     1   jayr0xx

  3     0   jayrox

  3     1   jayr0xx`

which i want to return:

  `system_id mic user_name

  1     1   jayr0xx

  3     0   jayrox`

this is driving me insane
i am writing this in PHP 5.3 (PDO)

Comment: your query does in fact return unique results.

Comment: hmm, ok. how would i make it give the wanted results?

Comment: Do you want to show the `max` of `mic`, the `sum` of `mic`, or something else?

Comment: first, you should clearly understand/articulate why those two rows are the ones you want.  I do not see a pattern based on your example.Then add some where clause condition or subquery to restrict to those 'important' rows

Comment: i want it to grab the user_name and mic assigned to the system_id for each system_id that the user_id has in the `users_systems` table

kind of hard to explain, i hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN users_gamernames ON (users_gamernames.user_id = users_systems.user_id and users_gamernames.system_id = users_systems.system_id)`

Because you left out the second join condition, you're getting the results for each user/system paired with each gamername.

Comment: i think this what i need, let me run it on a couple of my users and if it gives the results i want, i'll accept this answer.

Comment: as far as my testing goes this is exactly what i needed. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Natural Joint is what you have to use here.

```
SELECT DISTINCT system_id, mic ,user_name FROM users_systems NATURAL JOIN users_gamernames
```